# jQuery ui tabs rotate pause on hover

Tags: jquery-ui, rotation

I am working on a rotator using jquery ui and can get it to pause on hover with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#rotator").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
    $("#rotator").hover(  
        function() {  
            $("#rotator").tabs("rotate",0,true);  
        },  
        function() {  
            $("#rotator").tabs("rotate",5000,true);  
        }  
    );  
});
```

This only problem is that it stops on the last item in the list and won't rotate through the first item unless I make it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#rotator > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
    $("#rotator").hover(  
        function() {  
            $("#rotator").tabs("rotate",0,true);  
        },  
        function() {  
            $("#rotator").tabs("rotate",5000,true);  
        }  
    );  
});
```

but then the hover doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get it to cycle through the list and pause on hover?

Comment: Can you provide a quick example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see any other code you have affecting the ul?

Comment: Provide jsfiddle please

Comment: Ok, sorry it has taken me so long to get back. I have it running here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/steveeller/5W6Fw/  It is working with a hover...sort of. As long as you keep the mouse moving over the rotator. As soon as you stop, the rotation starts again. I am somewhat ok with that. The real problem is: 1.it won't cycle through the list. It gets to item 5, then shows the main area with a blank background and it stop the rotation. I have tried making it #rotator > ul, and it loops the rotation correctly, but I lose the pause functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had a really old version of jquery and jquery ui. I updated to the version we are running on our site (1.7.2 and jquery ui 1.82). Could run the newest versions, but we have too many issues with legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

guys!
I just commited an extension to make Pause on Hover for jQuery UI Tabs
[jQuery UI Tabs Rotate: Pause on Hover](https://github.com/tigusigalpa/jQuery-UI-tabs-Rotate-Pause-on-hover)

Enjoy it!